# How to pass ros-args in rclnodejs

Tags: ros

I am trying to encrypt my topic using certificates. I have created certificates and am passing it as args to my launch file. If i subscribe it using another launch file and same ros-args am getting the data. I need to know how to add ros-args in rclnodejs so that I can receive my data in node backend